# Why was I charged $26 for 1 ride on airtain and metro?

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city, fees-and-charges

I recently took the air train to Jamaica, NYC then metro to uptown. I paid all the fees by adding $26 to my card - to be ready for later rides. After getting to my hotel I went out to ride the metro and the card had a zero balance. I was confused, but added $22 more to be set for 3 days. What happened to my $26?

My understanding is - $7.50 for airport, $5 hidden fee, $2.50 for one way ride to midtown. So why did the balance become 0? My charge said Airtrain for Airtrain only. Can someone explain?

Comment: I think the phenomenon of *default city* applies, WRT lack of details.

Comment: A Google search reveals that Jamaica is a train station in New York

Comment: Where and how did you add the $26 to your card? Is it a new card? What type of Metrocard is it? Some allow you to review your trip history in your account.

Comment: There is no "hidden fee". As of thus writing, entering or exiting at Jamaica or Howard Beach stations costs $8.25, payable only with a Metrocard. All other Airtrain stations are free.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you accidentally purchased the 10-trip Metrocard. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirTrain_JFK):

> The AirTrain JFK 10-Trip MetroCard costs $25 and can be used for ten trips on the AirTrain within 31 days from first use

Comment: It was my thought as well but that doesn’t quite add up…

Comment: @jcaron The refillable Metrocard itself is $1, I believe.

Comment: But that would not account for the subway ride. Weird.